# how to set custom claim value in Azure AD SAML

Tags: azure-active-directory, saml-2.0, claims-based-identity

I'm setting up SAML SSO for an application.  I have it working except that I'm unable to return a suitable value for the NameID claim.  Existing userid's in the application are firstname + last initial so they don't match display names, email addresses, or any of the typical stuff found in Azure AD.  I could use a transform to generate that but the available functions don't appear to do what I need.

I could also manually enter the userid in Azure AD and then map the claim to that but I hate to "misuse" an existing field (e.g. putting the userid in user.jobtitle or some such).

I also don't want to have to change everyone's userid in the app to match something that already exists in Azure.

I feel like I'm missing something obvious here since there have to be a lot of apps that don't use a common Azure property as their userid.

Thanks in advance for any help here!

Tom

Comment: I'm aware that there are a number of extension attributes that might be used for this but they appear to all be sourced from on-prem AD, which I'm not using.  This is strictly cloud and I don't see any custom fields there.

Answer (score 0):

You can map the attributes & claims present in the active directory to your app fields. For example if `user.givenname` is present in the active directory and in your app, the field name is `firstName`, you can achieve this by doing the mapping in manage claim section of User attributes & claims. Same could be done for others fields.

You go into the `Enterprise applications > Your App > SAML-based Sign-on > click on edit`

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks.  Yes, I found that.  However, "user.givennam" (first name) is not the user's userid in this application.  Userid's in this app are firstname + first letter of last name -- e.g. the userid for "Bob Smith" would be "bobs".  I'm trying to figure out how to either construct that from user.givenname and user.surname or populate a custom AD field with the correct userid so that I can return that value for the claim.  If that's not possible, we'd have to change every user's userid to match something that AD already has.

Comment: In that case, you've to go with claims transformation. Taking two input claims and corresponding operator as per your requirement in order to produce final desirable outgoing claims.

Comment: Harry, do you know of a transform that will let me generate user.givenname & Left(1,user.surname)?  Oddly, there are transform functions for taking substrings based on other strings but I didn't see one that would let me take the first n characters.

Comment: Is there a reason why you do not have a mapping between emailid and the userid in your service provider(application)?

Comment: Do "Bob Smith" ,  "Bob Saget" , "Bob Swan" have the same userid of "bobs" in your application. That's the reason you use emailid as identifier in attributes.